# How to call external function in F# with arguments by reference?

Tags: f#, pinvoke, external, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to port a C# dll-Call to F#.

The C# call is:

```
[DllImport("swedll32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "swe_revjul")]
private extern static double ext_swe_revjul(double tjd, int gregflag, ref int year, ref int month, ref int day, ref double hour);
```

I've tried to write this in F# in half a dozen ways (at least!) but all to no avail.
Among them:

```
[<DllImport("swedll32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "swe_revjul")>]
extern double ext_swe_revjul (double tjd ) (gregflag:int) (year: int byref) (month: int byref) (day: int byref) (hour: double byref);
```

Or:

```
let ext_swe_revjul double (tjd:double) (gregflag:int) (year: int byref) (month: int byref) (day: int byref) (hour: double byref )
```

I tried writing the byref with an  qualifier or as "a:byref" - could somebody please help me? Thank you very much in advance!

Temporarily frustrated scientist who just wants to get his formulas in :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
extern static double ext_swe_revjul(double tjd, int gregflag, int* year, int* month, int* day, double* hour)
```

The declaration should more or less match the C signature.

EDIT:

As ildjarn pointed out,

```
extern static double ext_swe_revjul(double tjd, int gregflag, int& year, int& month, int& day, double& hour)
```

might be better.

Comment: This will work, but I think `int&` and `double&` would more closely match the C# code's semantics.

Comment: Good point. Although I would recommend matching the C sig, whatever that is.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, I found out about the difference between the two by a posting on http://pblasucci.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/managing-pointers-or-fs-platform-invoke-gotcha/. One declaration uses an unmanaged pointer, the other a managed one.